# How to set all the children to NULL in the trie

Tags: c, arrays, null, trie

I am trying to implement a trie in C. My code compiles correctly, but when I run it with valgrind it shows an error. here is the problematic part:

```
typedef struct node {
bool end;
struct node *chil[26];
} NODE;
int main()
{
   NODE* ne = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE)); 
   if(ne->chil[1] == NULL) printf("\nzwycięstwo!\n"); 
   free(ne);
   return 0;
}
```

and here is the error report:

> ==3346== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
>
> ==3346==    at 0x40076B: main (exp.c:21)
>
> ==3346==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
>
> ==3346==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64->linux.so)
>
> ==3346==    by 0x40075A: main (exp.c:20)`

I guess I have to explicitly say that

```
ne->chill = {NULL};
```

but this results in compiler error
"expected expression"

What should I do? Can I avoid going through the whole array to set pointers to NULL?

Comment: First you should check `ne` itself. Second you should not read uninitialised objects. "Can I avoid going through the whole array to set pointers to NULL?" - Don't use their values. But it would be easier to just follow C conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A loop is the only way to set all the pointers portably to a NULL value

```
for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
  ne->chil[i] = NULL;
```

You may hear suggestions to use `calloc` or `memset`. But a zero-bit pattern is not necessarily the same as a NULL value for a pointer. Even if many platforms implement it that way.

Comment: @Stargateur: A clever compiler might convert this to `memset` anyway (or an heavily optimised inlined variant), as he should know if the architecture uses an all-bits-zero representation for null pointers. Leave implementation details to the toolchain (unless you really identified this as a problem).